# Could not resolve type name error while performing search in Sitecore in Content tree

Tags: solr, content-search, sitecore-client

After logging to the Sitecore content tree, getting the below error while performing the search.

An error occured while searching. Rephrase the query.

> Could not resolve type name: 
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.Search.SearchSystemIndex, Sitecore.Kernel (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

The search is working fine when we perform search in web site. Using `SOLR 5.1` version for search.

Comment: Which version of Sitecore do you use?

Comment: @chorpo ...Sitecore 8.2 version.

Comment: did you upgrade your site from 7?

Comment: yes we have upgraded from 7.2 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Sitecore 7.2 you have bellow configurations into **\Website\App_Config\Include\Sitecore.ContentSearch.config** file :

```
<search>
        <!-- EXTEND SEARCH PIPELINE
             This processor executes search expressions that use the Sitecore.ContentSearch indexes when the Search.UseLegacySearchEngine setting is set to false.
        -->
        <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Search.SearchSystemIndex, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Client" />
      </search>
```

and into **web.config**

```
  <search>
    <!-- other processors -->
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Search.SearchSystemIndex, Sitecore.Kernel" />
    <!-- other processors -->       
  </search>
```

In Sitecore 8 these configurations doesn't exist.

Please comment these lines of code for a short fix. 
   Please compare your config files with config files from a clean Sitecore solution which has same release with your version.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. By doing what is suggested above, the error vanished but the search is not happening. For every search even if item is present in content tree, it show message as **"There is no Match"**

Comment: Like i said in answer, please compare config files with a  clean instalation, looks like your config files were not upgraded correctly

Comment: Thanks for your support. The search is happening now. Only changes I had done is commented the tag mentioned by  you in _**web.config**_

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue