# Sitecore Content Search is not working in the Content Editor

Tags: content-search, solr

I'm getting the following error while performing Sitecore content search:

> ERROR Could not resolve type name:
>   Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex,
>   Sitecore.Support.181761 (method:
>   Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode
>   configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

I have performed the following activities before posting this question here:

1. Checked the Log file and could not find any specific details apart from the error description.
2. Checked by Rebuilding the indexes and all indexes are running fine after performing rebuild indexes.
3. Tried to follow the suggestion as mentioned in the below sitecore stack exchange link but could not find the particular type name "Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex" in both Web.config as well as "Sitecore.ContentSearch.config as well:

[Could not resolve type name error while performing search in Sitecore in Content tree](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10583/could-not-resolve-type-name-error-while-performing-search-in-sitecore-in-content)

Can anybody please provide your suggestions/inputs on this?

Thanks and Regards

Vijayarajan Venkateswaran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception clearly states that it cannot find `Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex, Sitecore.Support.181761`.

It means you have a config file which points at the `Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.Client.Pipelines.Search.SearchContentSearchIndex`.

You need to have `Sitecore.Support.181761.dll` in your bin folder or remove the config.

Comment: Thanks Marek. I have added the Sitecore.Support.181761.dll in my bin folder and it worked great. Thanks a ton!